# how to show error when user search invalid movie data (omdb api with nodejs)

Tags: node.js

Here is the code for app.js

```
var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var request = require('request');
    var _und = require('underscore');

    app.set("view engine", "ejs");

    // Search Route
    app.get("/", function(req, res) {
        res.render("search");
    });

    // Result Route
    app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
        var query = req.query.search;
        var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=6cf73f27&s=" + query;
        // var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=6cf73f27&s=star";
       request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error && response.statusCode != 200) {
            res.render("search", {
                warning: "Movie is not in database"
            });

        } else {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render("results", {
                data: data
            });
        }
       });

    });

    app.listen(9090, function() {
        console.log("Movie App has started!!!.....Ctrl+C to Exit.....");
    });
```

Here is the code for my search result page:

```
    <h1>Result:</h1>
<ul>

<% data["Search"].forEach(function(movie) { %>
    <li><strong><%= movie["Title"] %></strong> - <%= movie["Year"]%></li>
<% }) %>
</ul>

<a href="/">Search again!</a>
```

When user search invalid or wrong typo movie
here is the error. I would like to pop up or show error and redirect back to search page.

```
TypeError: D:\Development App\nodejs(moviedb)\moviedbapp\views\results.ejs:4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check before rendering as api send `200` response code without error, following code may help you

```
// Result Route
    app.get("/results", function(req, res) {
        var query = req.query.search;
        var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=6cf73f27&s=" + query;
        // var url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=6cf73f27&s=star";
       request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        if(error && response.statusCode != 200) {
            res.render("search", {
                warning: "Movie is not in database"
            });

        } else {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            if( data.Response == 'False') {
                return res.render("search", {
                    warning: "Movie is not in database"
                });
            }
            res.render("results", {
                data: data
            });
        }
       });

    });
```